# Dynamically load page from unique identifier

Tags: php, dynamic

How would I go about this?

I am allowing users to sign in via various social websites. I get their unique identifiers and than redirect them to some other page

```
$id = ($profile->identifier);
$newURL = "/your-data/$id";
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

, where they will be able to store some data about themselves.

I know and I will get here all data neccessary and save it to database.

I would like, on /your-data/98432048320

show them website generated from /template/header,index,footer.php

Here is what I have done so far to get this working:

on your-data/index.php

```
<?php
include("templates/header.htm");

// Set the default name
$action = 'index';
// Specify some disallowed paths
$disallowed_paths = array('header', 'footer');
if (!empty($_GET['action'])) {
   $tmp_action = basename($_GET['action']);
   // If it's not a disallowed path, and if the file exists, update $action
   if (!in_array($tmp_action, $disallowed_paths) && file_exists("templates/{$tmp_action}.htm"))
       $action = $tmp_action;
}
// Include $action
include("templates/$action.htm");

include("templates/footer.htm");
?>
```

I can not get it to run. It`s just plain PHP, no frameworks...

Comment: its not enough information. How did you pass `get` param `action`? What will be the `action` for `/your-data/98432048320` path in your case?

Comment: Ok, I have not gone the right path. How would I do this: 

- on your-data/ get all relevant data (done) and save this data to DB (done)
- get unique identifier of a user and redirect him to this page (done)
- on this page, show the data from DB for that user (I know how to do this)

The problem here is, that user will always have unique ID, and I do not know how to prepare website for him. I have templates prepared (header, body, footer).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are the crucial differences between those templates. For example, you have templates: `98432048320.htm` and `98432048300.htm`. By what conditions they will differentiate in their content?

Comment: HTML-vise, they wont differenciate, I also know how to write queries (dynamic content on each of those sites) ... I just do not know how to handle "new page generation" (for each of those newly created IDS(98432048320.htm, 98432048300.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should not generate dozens of templates for each unique user. It would be quite redundant.
Instead, make one `php` file, let's call it `content.php` (whatever).
Such file can contain dynamically generated data respectively to certain user.
 Include `content.php` to your main `index.php`.
*your-data/index.php*:

```
<?php
include("templates/header.htm");

$action = 'index';   // Set the default name

if (!empty($_GET['action'])) {
   $tmp_action = basename($_GET['action']);

   if (is_numeric($tmp_action)){   // check if user identifier was passed in
       include("templates/content.php");
   }
}

include("templates/footer.htm");
?>
```

Now `$tmp_action` variable is freely accessible within `content.php`.
*content.php*:

```
<?php

    $userId = (int) $tmp_action;

    // possible case
    $query = "SELECT name, age, activity FROM social_users WHERE id = ". $userId;

    // here you can get all needed data for certain user 
    // which can be shown in #mainContainer div

?>
<div id="mainContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @RomanPerekhrest for your answer. 

It is pretty clear to me, that there is a better way, than creating page for each new user...
Thank you for your solution - but url will still not point to /your-data/$userId ...

I think I would have to do this with url rewrites?

Comment: of course, normally an application should have a single entry point - `index.php`. All further requests are dispatched through it.